# Python exit from all running threads on truthy condition

Tags: python, multithreading

I am using threads to check a header status code from an API url. How can i break loop/stop all other threads if condition is true. Please check following code..

```
import logging, time, threading, requests

#: Log items
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class EppThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, verbose=verbose)
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        startTime = time.time()
        url = self.args[0]
        limit = self.args[1]

        for i in range(limit):
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                break
                #Exit other similar threads (with same url)
            else:
                print('Thread {0} - success'.format(thread.getName()))

         print('process completed')
         # Send Email


number_of_threads = 5
number_of_requests = 100

urls = ['https://v1.api.com/example', 'https://v2.api.com/example']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()

    for url in urls:
        threads = []
        for i in range(number_of_threads):
            et = EppThread(name = "{0}-Thread-{1}".format(name, i + 1), args=(url, number_of_requests))
            threads.append(et)
            et.start()

    # Check if execution time is not greater than 1 minute  
    while len(threads) > 0 and (time.time() - startTime) < 60:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.isAlive():
                threads.remove(thread)
                print('Thread {0} terminated'.format(thread.getName()))

    os._exit(1)
```

Please suggest some better ways that stops code execution if condition gets true in any running thread.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to exit all thread, including the main, any time any of the threads has an improper connection (`response.status_code != 200`). Is that accurate?

Comment: @EricEdLohmar Yes that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

An important thing to note here is that when the `run` method of a `Thread` is complete, the `Thread` is set to dead and garbage collected. So all we really need is a boolean class variable that breaks that loop. Class variables are the same for all objects instantiated from that class and subclasses; so once we set it, all of the objects in our class will act the same way:

```
import logging, time, threading, requests

#: Log items
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)


class EppThread(threading.Thread):
    kill = False  # new Boolean class variable
    url = 'https://v1.api.com/example'  # keep this in mind for later

    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, verbose=verbose)
        self.args = args

    def run(self):
        limit = self.args[0]

        for i in range(limit):
            response = requests.get(self.url)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                self.kill = True  # ends this loop on all Threads since it's changing a class variable

            else:
                print('Thread {0} - success'.format(self.getName()))  # changed to self.getName()

            if self.kill:  # if kill is True, break the loop, send the email, and finish the Thread
                break

        print('process completed')
        # Send Email


number_of_threads = 5
number_of_requests = 100

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()

    threads = []
    for i in range(number_of_threads):
        et = EppThread(name="{0}-Thread-{1}".format(name, i + 1), args=(number_of_requests))
        threads.append(et)
        et.start()

    # Check if execution time is not greater than 1 minute
    while threads and time.time() - startTime < 60:  # removed len() due to implicit Falsiness of empty containers in Python
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.isAlive():
                threads.remove(thread)
                print('Thread {0} terminated'.format(thread.getName()))

    EppThread.kill = True
```

Now when any of the `EppThreads` has a bad connection it sets the class variable to `True`, which makes all of the other `EppThread`s break the loop as well. I also added `EppThread.kill = True` at the end so it'll break the request loops more cleanly if you exceed 1 minute run time.

Lastly, I added the `url` class variable. This is because you expressed interest in running different urls simultaneously and only kill the ones that specifically have a bad connection. All you have to do at this point is subclass `EppThread` and overwrite `kill` and `url`.

```
class EppThread2(EppThread):
    kill = False
    url = 'https://v2.example.com/api?$awesome=True'
```

Then you can instantiate `EppThread2` and add it to the `threads` list and everything should work as you want it to.

Comment: But how to tell main program to exit when condition meets True?

Comment: You can use the `exit()` builtin function. `if condition: exit()`

Comment: Nvm. I understand now. I'll create another answer based on my current understanding of your problem.

Comment: If i exit then it will exit all the script and would not send any email to me on completion.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have few questions... 1. Does it still process `# Send Email` after process completes the loop of its get exit immediately without finishing code inside `run` ?  2. Does `exit()' also stops other threads as well? I want to stop all other threads either if any of threads has bad network.or one thread has bad network and other threads have not.No matter what's the condition - just stop other threads as well if one has bad network. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Only the email in the thread that had the bad connection will send. Since all of the Threads are daemons, they will all quit once the main quits. Exit will quit the main, concordently quitting all remaining threads. If you want to send all of the emails, make another boolean variable in the main program and add it to the while condition, then replace `exit()` with `break` and add a final for loop after the while that sends the emails where possible, then exits.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without using `self.daemon` - sometimes i run 10 threads - 5 threads for `https://v1.api.com/example` and another 5 threads for `https://v2.api.com/example`.  I like your solution but this kills all threads even other threads with another API url.  Is there any way to kill only 5 threads of first group if HTTP error.  Should i use some sort of global variable/list to tell other threads if it should continue execution or not.  I hope you understand and once again thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The simplest way, assuming you used the recommendations from the last comment, would be to set `bad_conn` to true for each of the Threads you want to close in the final loop in the main program. I'll update my answer to take all of this info consideration once I get to a computer.

Comment: Rewrote the answer per the comments

Comment: Is there any way to avoid creating another class `EppThread2` I currently use for loop to create threads based on given urls. Can't we use some sort of list variable to know which url has failed and which should keep running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154553/discussion-between-eric-ed-lohmar-and-seoppc).

Answer (score 5):

You could create an [event object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) that's shared between all your threads that share the same url. When you run into an error in the thread, set the event. Then, in your run loop check for the event. If it has happend, kill the thread by breaking the loop.

Here's a version of your example modified to use the Event.

```
import logging, time, threading, requests

#: Log items
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)

class EppThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs=None, verbose=None, bad_status=None):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, group=group, target=target, name=name, verbose=verbose)
        self.args = args
        self.bad_status = bad_status

    def run(self):
        startTime = time.time()
        url = self.args[0]
        limit = self.args[1]

        for i in range(limit):
            if self.bad_status.is_set():
                # break the loop on errors in any thread.
                break
            response = requests.get(url)
            if response.status_code != 200:
                # Set the event when an error occurs
                self.bad_status.set()
                break
                #Exit other similar threads (with same url)
            else:
                print('Thread {0} - success'.format(thread.getName()))

         print('process completed')
         # Send Email


number_of_threads = 5
number_of_requests = 100

urls = ['https://v1.api.com/example', 'https://v2.api.com/example']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    startTime = time.time()

    threads = []
    for url in urls:
        # Create an event for each URL
        bad_status = threading.Event()
        for i in range(number_of_threads):
            et = EppThread(name = "{0}-Thread-{1}".format(name, i + 1), args=(url, number_of_requests), bad_status=bad_status)
            threads.append(et)
            et.start()

    # Check if execution time is not greater than 1 minute
    while len(threads) > 0 and (time.time() - startTime) < 60:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        for thread in threads:
            if not thread.isAlive():
                threads.remove(thread)
                print('Thread {0} terminated'.format(thread.getName()))

os._exit(1)
```

The `threading.Event` class works for both threads and processes. So, if at somepoint you wanted to switch to using Process it would "just work".

Comment: Does this approach handle urls separately? For example if url1 gets failed so only threads using url1 get stopped. Right?

Comment: It does. You're creating an event for each url in urls and then sharing that event will all the threads for that url.

Comment: You can't use `threads.remove` in a loop over the list.  Also, you're creating `threads` again for each `url`.

Comment: Eric, good edit. You may consider making the same change to OP's question. I copied the code verbatim and only added the Event handling.

Answer (score 1):

Import `sys`

Here is an example:

```
import sys

list = []
if len(list) < 1:
     sys.exit("You don\'t have any items in your list")
```